# ERC 20 Royalty implementation

Tags: erc-20, erc-20-approve, royalties

Hello Guys i want to implement a royalty fee on whenever my custom ERC20 token gets transfer between accounts any idea to implement this or any tutorial pls any help would be appreciated

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint amount) public {

    // calculate the share of tokens for your target address
    uint shareForX = amount/100;

    // save the previous balance of the sender for later assertion
    // verify that all works as intended
    uint senderBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    
    // check the sender actually has enough tokens to transfer with function 
    // modifier
    require(senderBalance >= amount, 'Not enough balance');
    
    // reduce senders balance first to prevent the sender from sending more 
    // than he owns by submitting multiple transactions
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
    
    // store the previous balance of the receiver for later assertion
    // verify that all works as intended
    uint receiverBalance = balanceOf[_to];

    // add the amount of tokens to the receiver but deduct the share for the
    // target address
    balanceOf[_to] += amount-shareForX;
    
    // add the share to the target address
    balanceOf[target] += shareForX;

    // check that everything works as intended, specifically checking that
    // the sum of tokens in all accounts is the same before and after
    // the transaction. 
    assert(balanceOf[msg.sender] + balanceOf[_to] + shareForX ==
        senderBalance + receiverBalance);
}
```

I have used this function and deployed the token on testnet(Rinkebay) but its not deducting the tax
I have also used the Basictoken.sol file does it overrride my my function??

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement 'tax' or 'fee' to your token. Because there are no royalties in ERC20s. Royalties are for NFTs, ERC721s.

You can override openzeppelin's transfer method. You can calculate fee amount and send it to your fee address, send all the rest to the `to` parameter.